# Convert a GET request into POST request

Tags: python, http, flask, flask-restful, rest

I have created a rest API in flask and used the GET method as follows

```
@app.route("/Api/getscore/",methods=["GET"])
def getscore():
    sex=request.args['sex']
    age=int(request.args['age'])
    address=request.args['address']
return jsonify({'result':some_method(all inputs)})
```

the getscore method takes many inputs. but i'm not posting them all due to code being private
but i learnt that using GET when there are many inputs is not secure . so i changed the method to POST but when i call the API using `http://localhost:5000/Api/getscore/?sex=M&age=18......` 
i'm getting method not allowed error 
how do i change the URL?
i got the result while using POST request in postman but it doesn't works in browser

Comment: That is expected I guess, as through browser you can only hit `GET` request, as you cannot create the `body` that you want to pass to the API.

Comment: Go through this like, https://www.geekstrick.com/python-http-get-and-post-methods-in-flask/, its helpful.

Comment: Where did you learn "that using GET when there are many inputs is not secure"? Not true. I think someone may be steering you off track there.

Comment: @COVFEFE-19 they might be referring to the data exposed in URL while using GET method